# Provisioning vagrant inside windows10 ubuntu fails

Tags: windows-10, vagrant

I am trying to provision [VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) inside bash on Ubuntu on Windows but I'm getting errors

```
denis@Denis-PC:/mnt/e/vagrant-local$ vagrant up --provision
/mnt/e/vagrant-local/Vagrantfile:9: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java in PATH, mode 040777
  __     ___     ___     __  ____
  \ \   / \ \   / \ \   / / |___ \
   \ \ / / \ \ / / \ \ / /    __) |
    \ V /   \ V /   \ V /    / __/
     \_/     \_/     \_/    |_____|

  Varying Vagrant Vagrants v2.1.0-master
  Docs:       https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/
  Contribute: https://github.com/varying-vagrant-vagrants/vvv
  Dashboard:  http://vvv.test

VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
denis@Denis-PC:/mnt/e/vagrant-local$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.4.0-43-Microsoft
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.4.0-43-Microsoft'
denis@Denis-PC:/mnt/e/vagrant-local$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.3.36
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-4.3.36 DKMS files...
dpkg: warning: version '*-*' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
It is likely that 4.4.0-43-Microsoft belongs to a chroot's host
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.
denis@Denis-PC:/mnt/e/vagrant-local$
```

I cannot get `linux-headers-4.4.0-43-Microsoft` so the `dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms` will fail.

I tried everything from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465454/problem-with-the-installation-of-virtualbox), but nothing worked.

Is there any workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it chokes on the -Microsoft part. I got it to work by executing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-43
```